# Append Only Once Inside an .Each Loop

Tags: javascript, jquery, loops

I'm building a feature where it tells a reader that they've already read a specific post. To do this, I need to to notify the user, and I'm doing so by appending an element to an .article. The problem I'm having, is that because I'm appending inside an .each loop, the element is appending 4 times.

Heres my code:

```
$('.article-container').each(function() {

    // CHECK IF THE DATA IS IN THE ARRAY    
    if(cookieValue.indexOf($(this).data('id')) != -1) {                     

        $(this).addClass('readit');                                         
        $('<h4 class="readit-alert">You&apos;ve read it!</h4>').appendTo('.article-container.readit');

    } else {

        // OTHERWISE, ADD CLASS NOT READ                
        $(this).addClass('notread');                                        

    }

});
```

And here is what it's returning:

```
<h4 class="readit-alert">You&apos;ve read it!</h4>
<h4 class="readit-alert">You&apos;ve read it!</h4>
<h4 class="readit-alert">You&apos;ve read it!</h4>
<h4 class="readit-alert">You&apos;ve read it!</h4>
```

How can write this to only append the "readit-alert" only once within the article-container?

Comment: returning false within a .each() callback will stop the loop from continuing.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Add `return false;` after the append if you want to stop the loop executing.

Otherwise, have a global `var appended = false;` outside the function, then set it to `true` once you've appended it.

That is:

```
var appended = false;

$('.article-container').each(function() {

    // CHECK IF THE DATA IS IN THE ARRAY    
    if(cookieValue.indexOf($(this).data('id')) != -1) {                     

        $(this).addClass('readit');   

        if (!appended){                                      
                $('<h4 class="readit-alert">You&apos;ve read it!</h4>').appendTo('.article-container.readit');
                appended = true;
        }
    } else {

        // OTHERWISE, ADD CLASS NOT READ                
        $(this).addClass('notread');                                        

    }

});
```

Comment: Will this still work if I'm needing to loop through multiple ".article-containers". I'm looping thru 10 posts at a time, this is why I ask.

Comment: Yes, the variable will only cause it to skip appending the HTML, the will still run over as many .article-container's there are (e.g. 10).

Comment: No problem. Would you mind accepting it? There's a green hollow tick next to the top of my answer which you'd need to click.

Answer (score 0):

After playing around with the code above, this is what got it working the way I needed it to work. Hope this helps.

```
var appended = false;

$('.article-container').each(function() {

    // CHECK IF THE DATA IS IN THE ARRAY    
    if(cookieValue.indexOf($(this).data('id')) != -1) {                     

        $(this).addClass('readit');   

        if (!appended){                                      
            $('<h4 class="readit-alert">You&apos;ve read it!</h4>').appendTo('.article-container.readit');
            appended = true;
        }

    } else {

        // OTHERWISE, ADD CLASS NOT READ                
        $(this).addClass('notread'); 
        appended = false;                    

    }

});
```